# Connecting Spartacus withe Backend public instance

Tags: javascript, frontend, spartacus-storefront

I am trying to connect to the public instance, however the link is not working :
https://spartacus-training.eastus.cloudapp.azure.com/electronics-spa/en/USD/

Comment: Unclear question

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

You can find a public instance by looking at our documentation https://sap.github.io/spartacus-docs/spartacus-faq/#is-there-a-demo-of-a-spartacus-based-storefront-available.

It currently points to https://spartacus-demo.eastus.cloudapp.azure.com/electronics-spa/en/USD/

If ever you need to use the backend public instance, look at the network tab, and use the provided server.